# How do I delete google.maps.Polyline object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, this

I have an (javascript) object that inherits from `google.maps.Polyline`. I want to be able to delete this object.  I don't want to just make the line disappear with `setMap(null)` or something like that.  I want it actually deleted, something like this (but I know this won't work):

```
myObject.prototype.destroy = function() {
    delete this;
}
```

What would be the best way to do this?  There are some other posts similar to this, but none seem to be answered.

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like?  I call delete on google.maps.Marker objects and google.maps.Polyline object (after hiding them).

Comment: OK, I might be able to do that, but why doesn't deleting them before hiding them make them disappear?  Also, what is the best way to have an object delete itself?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by deleting the object?

Comment: I want to line to disappear, I don't need the other data anymore, I don't want the list's that have references to it to be able to access any of its data.  There is no reason to have it around anymore, so why not delete it?

Answer (score 0):

`delete` doesn't delete objects, it removes properties from objects.

So when you like to remove a property from an object(the "lists", whatever it might be), you must delete the property of this object:

```
delete listObject.propertyThatHoldsTheReference
```